# Android Application Development for Dummies Silent Mode Toggle app not behaving properly

Tags: android

I'm just starting out with Android programming and am following along in the 'Android Application Development for Dummies' book, and have gotten to a point where I have a 'working' Silent Mode Toggle app, but I noticed a 'bug' or something:

When I adjust the volume with the volume buttons on my virtual device (or actual phone if I install it on there) and open the Silent Mode Toggle program it will not necessarily show the correct state of the phone's silent/ringer status. It always shows normal (the green image). So if I use the volume buttons on my button to bring it down to silent and open the app, it will still show the green image for 'normal' even though the phone is actually silenced.
However, if I use the APP to turn it to silent mode, leave the app, and come back, it properly shows the red image. I tried copying the code from the [downloaded MainActivity.java file](https://github.com/donnfelker/Silent-Mode-Toggle/blob/master/src/src/com/dummies/android/silentmodetoggle/MainActivity.java) to see if I had a typo in there somewhere, but it still exhibits the same behavior.

The example app in the book was written using Android 2.2, but I'm developing on 2.3.3 (my virtual device and actual phone)
Is there some difference in 2.2 and 2.3.3 that is causing this, or some other issue?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some further researching, I decided to try something.

On line 57 of the above reference java file:

```
if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
```

I changed it to read:

```
if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT || ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) {
```

and now it seems to work properly!

So maybe this is needed because as I mentioned, I'm using 2.3.3 as opposed to the 2.2 which was used in the book. Hopefully me inserting this line won't cause any issues as I go further along. And I haven't actually tested on my actual phone to see how an incoming call, text message, email, alarm, etc. is affected as far as being silent or not.